# Reactjs loop over array that calls a function which returns a list of divs leads to a missing key warning

Tags: reactjs

First time asking a question so please bare with the poor formatting.

I'm sorry for everyone who was here for the initial post. Here is a simpler form of the problem.

```
import { add, format } from "date-fns";
import React from "react";

function TasksPage() {
    const daysArray = Array(10)
        .fill()
        .map((_, idx) => add(new Date(), { days: idx }));

    return (
        <div key="someID">{daysArray.map((item) => someFunction(item))}</div>
    );
}

const someFunction = (date) => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div key={`${format(date, "d")}-div1`}>{`${format(
                date,
                "d"
            )}-div1`}</div>
            <div key={`${format(date, "d")}-div2`}>{`${format(
                date,
                "d"
            )}-div2`}</div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

export default TasksPage;
```

The issue is when I call Taskpage as such...

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import TasksPage from "./pages/TasksPage";


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<TasksPage />);
```

I get the following warning.

react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:87 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `TasksPage`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
at TasksPage

I don't understand which element I could possibly be missing?

Any hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: can you share what displayColumn does?

Comment: Please include all relevant code you've an issue working with in a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We can't see what is being rendered or where any React keys are being used (*or not*). What is `displayColumn` function returning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning comes in this code

```
function TasksPage() {
    const daysArray = Array(10)
        .fill()
        .map((_, idx) => add(new Date(), { days: idx }));

    return (
        <div key="someID">{daysArray.map((item) => someFunction(item))}</div> // Warning raised here.
    );
}
```

You should add a key to each child as well **as each element inside the children** so that React can handle minimal DOM changes.
You can write your code like the one below.

```
return (
  <div key="someID">
    {daysArray.map((item) => (
      <div key="{randomId}">{setTemplateName("")} || ''</div>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

You can use the index as a key for your children but as per the documentation, that's not a good way to implement it. You can the detailed explanation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children). Instead of that, you can use some randomly generated IDs like `UUID` or `nanoid`.